# How to fix this Problem, node:internal/process/promises:279 -- triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, promise

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

const executePy = (filepath) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(
      `python ${filepath}`,
      (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        error && reject({ error, stderr });
        stderr && reject(stderr);
        resolve(stdout);
      }
    );
  });
};
```

When i try to run a python file useing nodejs then i get this error

```
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "#<Object>".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

Exeecute the python file and return the output

Comment: what exactly you are using (library or anything) to execute python?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.